# Understanding java final variables

Tags: java, string, final

Can you please help me understand what happens if final variables are used in String concatenation?
   this is a certification question, so is not a question about how to compare string

```
String var1 = "varan";       
String an = "an";
final String an2 = "an";
System.out.println(var1 == ("var"+an));       
System.out.println(var1 == ("var"+an2));
```

Output  :

```
false
true
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `final`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I believe their question is about why concatenating with a `final` value results in the same `String` as the literal, when concatenating with the non-`final` value doesn't.

Comment: The `final` may prevent string interning, but I am not sure that it is guaranteed to since you are adding the strings together to create a new one.

Comment: Hi thanks for asking, this is a certification question, so i need to understand the results,

Comment: @resueman: OP edit question with `this is a certification question, so is not a question about how to compare string` line and in comment OP want to  understand  result. thats why i provided my vote to reopen or TAsk answer is also explaining every line of posted snippet by OP.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK But that duplicate explained why it was happening. It wasn't about comparing `String`s. I guess it doesn't really matter though.

Comment: In working with Java since version 1.1, I have never cared a hoot about whether a String was interned or not.  Makes me question whether an official Java Certification is worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Because `"var"+an` is a different `String` `Object` newly created during *runtime* while `"var"+an2` is compile time constant which is interned, and refer to the the same address where `var1` is referencing.

---

Consider following example which is similar to your code.

```
public class TestString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stackOverflow = "stackOverflow";
        String overflow = "Overflow";

        final String overflowFinal = "Overflow";

        if (overflow == overflowFinal) {
            System.out.println("Both overflows are same!");
        }

        if (stackOverflow == ("stack" + overflow)) {
            System.out.println("Stack and overflow have same reference !");
        }

        if (stackOverflow == ("stack" + overflowFinal)) {
            System.out.println("Stack and overflowFinal have same reference !");
        }
    }

}
```

It will give following output :

```
Both overflows are same!
Stack and overflowFinal have same reference !
```

First of all kindly note that `==` compares the references of `Strings` and not the actual value.

[JLS 15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) states that,

> The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand operand in the **newly** created string.
>
> The String *object* is **newly** created (§12.5) *unless* the expression is a constant expression (§15.28).

So, from above statements we can say `"stack" + overflow` will be similar to `String newString = new String("stackOverflow");` (Internally *compiler* will use `StringBuilder` to perform this concatenation).

For the `final` `String` [JLS 4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) states,

> A variable of primitive type or type `String`, that is `final` and initialized with a *compile-time constant expression* **(§15.28)**, is called a constant variable.
>
> *and so* [§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) says
>
> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> ...
>
> - The additive operators `+` and `-`
>
> ...
>
> Compile-time constant expressions of type `String` are always "**interned**" so as to share unique instances, using the method [`String.intern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()).

Now, above statements says if we declare `String` as a `final`, it ultimately becomes *constant expression*.

Note that `String` literals are also interned.

Interned `String` means if you are creating the `String` and one `String` with the same content(*checked by* `.equals()` *method*)  which is already there in memory then it will not create new `String` but it will refer to the **same** memory location.

For example,

```
String a = "test";//String literals
String b = "test";
System.out.println("Is a & b interned ? :"+(a == b));
```

**Output :**

```
Is a & b interned ? : true
```

Comment: String literals are *always* interned, regardless of `final`. The literals referenced by `var1` and `an` are also interned, so that part of your answer explains nothing.

Comment: Your reasoning still isn't sound. Constant string expressions are interned, and string expressions containing only final string variables or literals are constant.